# Why is `x === x++` true and `x++ === x` false in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can you explain the difference between these two logical operations :

```js
let x = 1;

console.log('x = ' + x);
console.log('x ===  x++ : ' + (x ===  x++));

x = 1;

console.log('x = ' + x);
console.log('x++ ===  x : ' + (x++ ===  x));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *postfix increment* (`y = x++`), does increase the value, but evaluates to it's previous value. It barely equals:

```
  x² = x; // evaluate previous value of x
  x += 1; // increase x
  y = x²; // use previous value
```

So therefore `x === x++` is equal to:

```
  // evaluate left side of ===
  x¹ = x;
  // evaluate right side
  x² = x;
  // ++
  x += 1;
  // comparison
  x¹ === x² // true
```

wereas `x++ === x` is:

```
  // evaluate left side
  x¹ = x;
  // ++
  x += 1;
  // evaluate right side
  x² = x; // x was already incremented!
  // comparison
  x¹ === x²
```

Answer (score 4):

x ===  x++ : first compare x with x then x++
x++ === x : first x++ and then compare the result of  x++ with x

Comment: This doenst answer the question. Why would the compiler do that?

Comment: the compiler executes the code from left to right and do what i said

Answer (score 3):

When evaluting the `===` operator in javascript, it evalate the left operand first， and then the right operand, and does the comparison in the last. See [ecma262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

And, when `x++` is evaluted, the value of `x` is changed, and the result of `x++` is the original (unchanged) value of `x`.

So, in `x === x++` ，both `x` and `x++` evalutes to the original value of `x`，the value of `x` is changed after that. So the result is `true`.

In `x++ === x`,  the value of `x` is changed when evaluating the left `x++`, and the left operand evaluates to the original value. But the right operand eveluates after this, so it evaluates to the changed value of `x`. So the result is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

x++ is a post increment operator, it basically put the value of x already and then increment it by 1.
 In the first case `x===x++`. It suggests, `1===1` while in the second case `x++===x` ,the value of x is incremented before the comparison, So it becomes `1===2`,which is false of course.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the order of increment operator (before or after the variable) matters.

Using `x++` will return the variable first then increment it, while using `++x` will increment it first then return the result.

Example:

```
x = 0;
console.log(x++, x); // 0, 1 (first return the variable then increment)
console.log(++x, x); // 2, 2 (first increment then return the variable)
```

In the first comparison, you are incrementing it after all uses of variable:

```
x = 0;
//    0 === 0
      x === x++
```

In the second comparison, you first use the x value, then increment it and compare with new x value:

```
x = 0;
//    0   === 1
      x++ === x
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

In the second case, `x++` is being evaluated as `1` then it increments `x` (becomes 2). So the comparison ends up being `1 === 2`

Answer (score 0):

This is basic computer science, `x++` means use then update.

```
x = 1; 

x === x++
```

here value of x is changed after comparison is over.

```
x++ ===  x
```

here in beginning,  x++ value remains 1 but once === is executed, value of x changes to 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value x is incremented just before you read it again so x++ === x is false and x === x++ is true. 
There is some other operator that looks almost the same ++x which increments variable immediately.

```js
let x = 0;
console.log(x++); //0
console.log(x); //1
let y = 0;
console.log(++y); //1
console.log(y); //1
```

Answer (score 0):

**The operators ++ can be placed either after a variable.**

When the operator goes after the variable, it is in “postfix form”: x++.

The “prefix form” is when the operator goes before the variable: ++x.

```js
let x = 1;

console.log('x = ' + x);
//print x = 1
console.log('x ===  x++ : ' + (x ===  x++));
//(x ===  x++) that means
//(1 === 1)
//true

x = 1;

console.log('x = ' + x);
//print x = 1
console.log('x++ ===  x : ' + (x++ ===  x));
//(x++ ===  x) that means
//(1 === 2) works the same as x = x + 1, but is shorter
// false
```

Answer (score -1):

First, I assume that the expression is evaluated from **left to right**, see the demonstration below:

```js
console.log('(1 == 2) == 2 - left first          - ', (1 == 2) == 2 )
console.log('1 == (2 == 2) - right first         - ', 1 == (2 == 2) )
console.log('1 == 2 == 2   - same as left first  - ', 1 == 2 == 2   )
```

or [in ECMA 262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
[image]

---

**Theory done**, so in `x === x++`, **under the hood** it transplies to

```
// init temporary variables x_left/x_right in CPU for the calculation
x_left = x_right = x; 

// `===` is evaluated first:
x_left === x_right; // true

// then `x++` evaluate, doesn't affect the result `true` above
x_right += 1; 
x = x_right;
```

And in `x++ === x`, it transpiles to

```
// init temporary variables for the calculation (in CPU)
x_left = x_right = x;

// `x++`
x_left += 1;
x = x_left;

// `===` operator
x_left === x_right; // false
```

Answer (score -2):

`x ===  x++`  Here, `x=1` before comparing, so returns true.

`x++ ===  x`   Here, because of operator precedence,
              this equals `x === ++x` where x is incremented and hence returns false.